# getLastIndexOf(int item) LinkedList

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, lastindexof

I'm currently a freshman comp sci student working on learning data structures both through my class and also online.

I'm new to stack too but it has helped me a lot in the past.

My current problem is searching through a LinkedList to return the last index of which the number appears in the list.

I feel like this has to do somewhat with recursion and continually searching until you can somehow check for sure that that is the last occurrence of that item, then return its index.

However my first semester Java course did not cover recursion at all and I'm sort of at a loss.

Being in these courses I'm not asking for the flat out answer, I just need some direction. Or reassure me that I'm on the right path with looking into recursion at all?

Also, here is what I have attempted so far. Thanks for the help!

```
public int getLastIndexOf(int lastItem) { //goal is to return the lastindex at which that number appears last
    Node current;
    current = head;
    int count = 0; //count variable 
    while (current.next != null) { //go through list
        if (current.dataItem == lastItem) { 
            //check rest of the list for if that number exists beyond
        }
        count++; //increment count for every time loop executes
        current = current.next; //moves onto next node to check
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: "Perhaps some resources for learning recursion?" don't ask for links to tutorials, question will get closed. I will remove that bit for you.

Comment: Okay, my bad. I'm new here.

Comment: This is a singly-linked list, correct? Because if it were doubly-linked, the obvious solution would be to search from the end backwards.

Comment: Yes singly-linked list

Comment: @Pansock Since you are new here, please note that if you find that any of the answers are useful you can vote them up (for your own questions initially) and if you feel someone has answered your question click on the tick mark near the question to accept that answer. It's a way of appreciating the effort people put into writing answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the list to be a node followed by another list, called the tail. This is pseudocode, note you need two methods, the `private` one takes a node, this is the sub list.

```
public int getLastIndexOf(value) {
    return getLastIndexOf(head, value);
}

private int getLastIndexOf(sublist, value) {
    //check the tail first (because we want last index)
    if (sublist.tail != null) {//list has a tail
        int lastIndexInTail = getLastIndexOf(sublist.tail, value); //recursion
        if(lastIndexInTail != -1)
          return lastIndexInTail + 1; //it's in the sub list, the sub list starts at idx 1
    }

    // it's not in the tail, check this head
    if (sublist.data == value){
      return 0; //it's at the front of this list
    }

    return -1; //it's not in the head or in the tail of sublist
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar but was getting thrown the famous stack overflow error because of my logic and not being familiar with how to handle recursive functions. I appreciate the help and guidance in what I should have in future posts!

Comment: Well if you are getting stack overflow, why don't you edit question and put that code in? Someone can point out what was wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could just save and overwrite the index when you have a match like so:

```
public int getLastIndexOf(int lastItem) { //goal is to return the lastindex at which that number appears last
    Node current;
    current = head;
    int count = 0; //count variable
    int lastIndex = 0;
    while (current.next != null) { //go through list
        if (current.dataItem == lastItem) { 
                lastIndex = count;
        }
        count++; //increment count for every time loop executes
        current = current.next; //moves onto next node to check
    }
return lastIndex;
```

So you will save the position of the match in lastIndex, and if theres more than one match, you will just overwrite it with the "latest" value.

Comment: This would work, and better solution than recursion, but OP is asking for recursion.

Comment: This is great for iteratively overwriting like you said but I'm trying to take it from a recursive approach as I know it'll be useful later on when learning new data structures. I appreciate the help though!

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to do it by recursion**

This tutorial from [Topcoder](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/an-introduction-to-recursion-part-1/) might be useful here.

My 2 cents follow:

Recursion and iteration (looping, like for, while etc.) can be used to solve your current problem.

Your current code is not recursive, it is iterative. Recursion happens when you call the same function again and again till some end condition.

A recursive function has two parts:

1. the base condition - tells you when to stop the recursion
2. the recursive condition - tells you when to do recursion

Let's see this with an example. Say you want to print "Hello World" 10 times. Here's how you would do it iteratively

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

And here is how you do it recursively

```
void helloWorldPrinter(int index){
   //This is the base condition, tells us to stop when we've reached 10
   if(index == 10){
      return;
   }
   else{
      //Print for the n th hello world
      System.out.println("Hello World");
      //call the same function for printing the next (n+1 th) hello world
      helloWorldPrinter(index+1); //Looks similar to the i++ in the loop right?
   }
}
```

Recursion is incredibly useful in Binary Trees which are data structures that look like upside down trees. A concept that you can keep in mind while writing iterative *vs* recursive code is that iteration is like looking at the data structure as an observer and doing actions on it.Recursion proceeds as if you are an element in the data structure - you do your job and pass the responsibility to the next element (next recursive call)

Now I believe you can extend this logic to finding the last item in the Linked List. Though an iterative solution for this would be much easier than a recursive one.

The logic is:

```
Loop over list (iterative or recursive)
  If element is found, note down the index
End Loop if list has been traversed completely
return the element index
```

Comment: Really helpful with getting a base understanding of what recursion is versus iterative loops. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Pansock happy learning. You might want to look at [geeks for geeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures/) for more data structure related problems and solutions